# Creating static paths with multiple constrained params

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm now in the process of developing my small project and I'm not sure if it's even possible to do this the way I will describe below, so... I have dynamic routes like "/[community]/[townName]". How can I generate static paths where [townName] is constrained to [community]?

In other words - let's say we have townName "abc1". This town is in community "xyz1" so the page /xyz1/abc1 should be accessible and NOT throw 404. But there is also town with the same name "abc1" in "xyz2". So the path /xyz2/abc1/ should also be accesible.
However there is no town with same name in community xyz3 so I do not want to generate page for /xyz3/abc1/ - user should see 404 error.

Of course each town has it's unique ID in database and I could use it to generate pages, but I want my url to be SEO friendly.

All help and tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Only generate the paths you want available inside `getStaticPaths`. Can you show how you're currently doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths) and [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) from official Next.js website. It has more than one way to do what you want but there are additional customization options.